# Bukkit - Track Projectiles

Tags: java, bukkit

How would I track projectiles/entities that are created by:

```
Egg egg = (Egg) ((ProjectileSource) player).launchProjectile(Egg.class);
```

and find out which block the egg has landed on?

I would also like to disable chicken spawning from these eggs.

Answer (score 1):

To get where the egg lands, it seems quite [complex](https://bukkit.org/threads/how-to-get-the-block-where-an-egg-lands.201423/). If it's fine for you to just get the block the projectile is in, you can use this:

```
@EventHandler
public void onProjectileHit(ProjectileHitEvent e) {
    if (e.getEntity().getType() == EntityType.EGG) {
        Block block = e.getEntity().getLocation().getBlock();
    }
}
```

Preventing chickens from spawning from eggs is trivial:

```
@EventHandler
public void onCreatureSpawn(CreatureSpawnEvent e) {
    if (e.getSpawnReason() == CreatureSpawnEvent.SpawnReason.EGG) {
        e.setCancelled(true);
    }
}
```